# Parse LiveQueries active subscriptions list

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to create a cloud job that does something for each client that has an active LiveQuery subscription.

Is there a way to achieve that list of users/connections trough cloud code?

Answer (score 0):

Start the liveQuery server explicitly (e.g. by *not* providing options.startLiveQueryServer or options.liveQueryServerOptions)

```
const liveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(server, options.liveQueryServerOptions);
```

`liveQueryServer.clients` is what you need. Don't modify this map!